# startx inconsistent behavior

Tags: shell-script, ssh, xorg, docker, xinit

I have a SSH server that is responsible for running `dwm` binary through X forwarding, on my client computer, i have a shell script that replaces the `dwm` binary on `/usr/local/bin`, inside that script, i simply make a call to the server requesting it to run the original `dwm`:

```bsh
ssh -q -tt user@172.17.0.2 dwm $@
```

With only a single `-t`, i get the following error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal
```

---

On the SSH server side, i'm making use of `ForceCommand` to pass the parameters received through a `container_runner` script, it looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

The reason for the `ForceCommand` here is to limit the possibility of running anything else other than a set of Docker container initialization scripts (located on `/usr/local/bin`)

Here's an example of one of those scripts, the one below runs the `dwm` Docker image:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
docker run \
    --pull=never \
    --rm \
    -v container-scripts:/container-scripts \
    -v ssh-keys:/home/dwm/.ssh \
    -v x11-shared:/tmp/.X11-unix \
    -it \
    -e DISPLAY=:1 \
    -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.X11-unix/container-cookie \
    dwm \
    $@ 2>/dev/null
```

- `container-scripts` - volume containing a set of scripts that will allow running others sibling containers inside containers
- `ssh-keys` - the SSH keys in order to be able to run containers from inside other containers
- `x11-shared` - X11 shared data (X11 socket and xauth cookie)

---

My `ssh_config` looks like this:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
PreferredAuthentications=publickey
```

Things started to get inconsistent after i disabled SSH multiplexing from my `ssh_config`, previously with the settings below, it worked fine all the time (which makes no sense, as far as i know, SSH multiplexing shouldn't interfere in that), settings below:

```
ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
ControlMaster auto
ControlPersist yes
```

What happens is that whenever i try to run `startx` passing as argument my `dwm` script that makes a request to the SSH server to run the actual `dwm`, i just get a black screen, and nothing happens, it just stays like that, example below:

```bsh
startx /usr/local/bin/dwm -- :1
```

But, if i run the same command above, slightly differently, using shell command substitution alongside with the shell noop operator, it works fine (just takes a few more seconds to show `dwm` than usual, probably due to the ugly hack)

```bsh
: $(startx /usr/local/bin/dwm -- :1)
```

Comment: Double quote all variables when you use them. In particular unquoted `$@` is not useful

Comment: @roaima But wouldn't double quoting `$@` make them be parsed as a single argument, instead of multiple separated ones?

Comment: No. It means that "$@" is expanded into its corresponding zero or more values. I suspect that double quoting will actuallu solve the problems you're seeing

Comment: Tried quoting the `$@` on both server-side and client side scripts (including the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` on the `container_runner` script), still had no luck on getting it to work

Comment: I am confused about what you are trying to archive. X always has been a client/server system. When you use X forwarding via ssh, the local machine acts as the X server (and needs a running X server in the first place), while the remote machine doesn't need an X server. So, no `startx` should be involved in that **at all**. If you have started the X server already on your local machine **without** a window manager (WM), and you want to use `dwm` on the remote machine, you can just start it on the remote machine (again, without `startx`). If you have a local WM running, that will be used.

Comment: But that's what i'm doing, i have a `dwm` shell script that sends the `dwm` command to the SSH server, which subsequently is parsed as a Docker container name, and this same container is started on the server-side, using `startx` or `xinit`, specifying the `dwm` script as a CLI parameter of `startx` or putting it into `.xinitrc`, any of those worked for me

Comment: could it be that ssh is consuming all the stdin... try ssh -n to make sure ssh won't consume the stdin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find a solution for that, for some reason, the problem was in the fact that i was:

- Forcing TTY allocation, had to remove `-tt` flag from SSH client
- Requesting Docker to allocate a pseudo-tty and run in interactive mode, had to remove `-it` flags from Docker CLI on the SSH server side

> The points above only applies to graphical applications, like `st` and `firefox`, containers that are interactive, but not graphical (`fish` shell and `neovim`) still needs both flags above, `-tt` on the SSH client and `-t` on Docker CLI